# The program '[3708] BookLogistics.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff)

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app. I suddenly faced an issue in which Windows Phone 8.1 emulator starts but app doesn't start and a file named 'App.g.i.cs' opens up and highlights the below line of code:
`global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();`

This code is contained inside the following code:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
};
#endif
```

This happened after I installed Windows Phone 10 Emulator, I tried uninstalling WP 10 emulator but still facing the same problem.

I tried to find the solution but didn't find any solution. I don't know whether I'm right or not but all I got to know is that application 'breaks' when Debugger is enabled.

**Output:**
[image: Output]

Below is the screenshot of the problem:
[image]

**Solution:**
After doing a bit of experiment I found that in the `MainPage.xaml` I've included a `<TextBox>` and after removing the following code from `<TextBox>` the app works perfectly:

```
 <TextBox.Header>
     <TextBlock Text="Email" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS"/>
 </TextBox.Header>
```

Comment: What is the exception you get? You can find it out by hovering over `e`.

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev e.Exception {"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."}

e.Message "Unspecified error\r\n"

((System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException)e.Exception).ErrorCode -2147467259

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is strange, actually. That shouldn't happen. But that is no surprise for me as XAML controls in WP8 are buggy in comparison to Win8 controls.

The workaround is to use `HeaderTemplate` instead:

```
<TextBox Header="Email">
    <TextBox.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text={Binding} FontFamily="Comic Sans MS"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TextBox.HeaderTemplate>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: It says that property 'HeaderTemplate' doesn't support values of type 'TextBox'.